# Node EventEmitter manage listener pool

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events, eventemitter

I'm trying to notify periodically all clients about changes in sports matches, for which I use Eventemitter in node. The notification works fine, the issue I have is that if the client closes/refreshes the browser window, I should remove the listener on the server and decrease the pool of listeners, otherwise I could easily bump into memory leak warnings.

Code:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Stream = new EventEmitter();

exports.getScheduleUpdates = async (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive'
    });

    Stream.on('push', (data) => {
        let isAlive = res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
        if (!isAlive) {
            console.log("Should terminate");
        }
        console.log(isAlive);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
    Stream.emit('push', { match: 'sending some data' });
}, 10000);
```

When I run it locally and refresh the browser for example 2 times, the event fires for 3 clients, 2 of which are closed and the res.write returned false.

I got this far with the help of Google, but I can't figure out how to handle the listener pool for the event and remove them if the isAlive flag is false. Not 100% sure if relying on res.write return value is correct.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found this tutorial:
https://alligator.io/nodejs/server-sent-events-build-realtime-app/

Which ended up working well for my case.

```
let connectedClients = [];
exports.getScheduleUpdates = async (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive'
    });

    const clientId = Date.now();
    const newclient = {
        id: clientId,
        res
    }
    connectedClients.push(newclient);

    req.on('close', () => {
        connectedClients = connectedClients.filter(c => c.id !== clientId);
    });
}

function sendScheduleUpdates(changesToSend) {
    connectedClients.forEach(client => {
        client.res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(changesToSend)}\n\n`);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
    sendScheduleUpdates([{ match: 'sending some data' }]);
}, 10000);
```

Closing of old, unused responses is done in `res.on('close', () => {...})` part.